# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} (x^{x^{x}} - x^x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I was solving some problems on limits and derivatives and encountered this question, $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} (x^{x^{x}} - x^x)$$ The answer given is equal to $-1$.
I know that $x^{x^x}$ is smaller than $x^x$ as $x \to 0$ . For eg. $(0.1)$ <  $(0.1)^{0.1}$ which is 0.79,

So $0.1^{0.1^{0.1}} < 0.1^{0.1}$
, But I was having some difficulty in evaluating it properly.

Comment: Hint: what is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}x^x$?

Comment: This pdf might help you...[limits of x^x^x......^x](http://www.ww.ingeniousmathstat.org/sites/default/files/J09727._Marshall_Ash.pdf)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $$  x^{x^x}=e^{x^x\log x}=e^{e^{x\log x}\log x}$$ and

$$x^x=e^{x\log x}$$ thus the limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\Big( e^{e^{x\log x}\log x}\space -\space e^{x\log x}\Big)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^{e^{x\log x}\log x}-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^{x\log x}$$

Now it is easy to see that the first limit is $0$ and second is $1$; thus the different is $-1$.

Comment: That was really helpful